# Gráfico de função definida por partes no R

Tags: r, funções, plot

Estou tentando construir o gráfico da função abaixo no R:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei o código abaixo:

```
fa <- function(x){
  ifelse((x <= -0.5),x^2+x, ifelse((x>-0.5 & x< 0.5),x, ifelse((x>= 0.5),x-x^2,NA)))
}
plot(fa,xlim=c(-5,5), ylim = c(-1, 1), col = "red",
     panel.first = grid(20, 20, lty = 1, lwd = 1))
```

No entanto, o gráfico gerado apresenta ligações estranhas entre as partes, conforme indicam as setas na seguinte figura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual a mudança no código seria necessária para corrigir esse erro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui vai uma solução.
O truque é atribuir valores `NA` imediatamente antes do primeiro ponto de quebra e imediatamente depois do segundo ponto de quebra.

Para isso calcula-se a diferença entre valores consecutivos de `x` com `diff` e fica-se com um desses valores. É preciso ter `step[1]` devido a erros no cáculo em vírgula flutuante, em princípio os valores devem ser todos iguais.

```r
fa <- function(x, n){
  if(missing(n) || is.null(n)) n <- 101
  y <- x
  i <- x < -1/2
  j <- x >= 1/2
  y[i] <- x[i] + x[i]^2
  y[j] <- x[j] - x[j]^2
  #
  # remover as linhas que ligam os ramos
  # da função com valores NA em y
  step <- unique(diff(x))[1]
  is.na(y) <- x < -1/2 & x >= -1/2 - step
  is.na(y) <- x >= 1/2 & x < 1/2 + step
  #
  y
}

curve(fa, from = -1, to = 1,
      panel.first = grid(20, 20, lty = 1, lwd = 1))
```

[image]

```r
curve(fa, from = -1, to = 1,
      panel.first = grid(20, 20, lty = 1, lwd = 1),
      n = 301)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa é fazer isso usando o [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2). Para fazer isso usamos a geometria `geom_function`. É importante notar que dados não são necessários. Basta passar como argumento a função `fa` criada pelo RuiBarradas (vou omitir para tornar a resposta mais curta).

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
    geom_function(fun = fa)
```

[image]

Mas note que para reproduzir o caso da pergunta devemos incluir uma camada a mais em nosso gráfico. Por padrão o `geom_function` calcula os valores da função para x entre 0 e 1. Para mudar esse comportamento basta incluirmos um limite diferente para o eixo X com `xlim`.

```r
ggplot() +
    geom_function(fun = fa) +
    xlim(-2, 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>